# Cursor to update each row selected from multiple tables on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cursor

My situation is like, I have tables `table1` and `table2`.

`table1` has columns `DateCreated`, `ID` and `table2` has `SolutionProvided`, `ID`.

I have to find IDs where solution is provided before `DateCreated`.

So I wrote a query using joins through which I got the 'negative time' against the IDs.

Eg.  table1

```
ID  DateCreated        
_______________________    
1   06/20/2015 12:00:30
```

table2

```
 ID  SolutionProvided
__________________________
 1   06/19/2015 `12:00:30
```

The query returns:

```
ID  TimeDifference
____________________
1   -1440
```

`TimeDifference` returns difference in minutes. Here 1440 means 24 hrs * 60.

Now I need to make a cursor that would update this time (-1440) to a positive value i.e., -1440+1440+10 (addition of 10 minutes in each row)

So the cursor would finally update SoutionProvided of table2 to `06/20/2015 12:10:30`.

How to make a cursor like that? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could help you:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @IdToUpdate nvarchar(200) 

DECLARE crs CURSOR
FOR SELECT b.id from table1 a join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID where   DATEDIFF(min,DateCreated,SolutionProvided)  < 0

OPEN crs 

FETCH NEXT FROM crs 
INTO @IdToUpdate


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    update table2 set SolutionProvided = dateadd(min,ABS(DATEDIFF(min,DateCreated,SolutionProvided))+10,SolutionProvided) where ID = @IdToUpdate


    FETCH NEXT FROM crs 
    INTO @IdToUpdate

END 
CLOSE crs;
DEALLOCATE crs;
```

Or just an update script:

```
update b
set b.SolutionProvided = dateadd(min,ABS(DATEDIFF(min,DateCreated,SolutionProvided))+10,b.SolutionProvided)
from table1 a join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID 
where DATEDIFF(min,DateCreated,SolutionProvided) < 0
```

Comment: You should preferably **avoid** cursors and just use a simple, set-based `UPDATE` statement ...

Comment: The man wanted a cursor....i gave him one ! I know it can make a simple update select

Comment: But it will just do for -1440 minutes field. I need to update every row with whatever time fetched with an addition of 10 minutes. If it's  -10 it should increase it by +10+10  to make an overall increase of 10 minutes. 
And thanks for making the cursor for me! Much appreciated.

Comment: i have update the script for you. should work i think. i did not tested it .

Comment: a simpler version would be `set b.SolutionProvided = dateadd(min, 10, a.DateCreated)`...

Comment: Please see that the date just doesn't need to be incremented by 10, suppose the TimeDifference comes to  '-x'  so SolutionProvided  needs to be incremented by  +x and then +10, So that the values in SolutionProvided become positive first then are incremented by 10 mins.

Comment: No @dzomba. The issue is, the resulted  value (negative) I got from the two tables needs another variable to store it which then can be used to perform calc of adding time and then update all rows of table2. Your code is simply adding time to a specific row.

Comment: It a adding time to all rows that have negative difference. You don t really know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and got the working solution to my problem, just adding one more variable will work. Thanks guys for the help.

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @IdToUpdate nvarchar(200) 
    DECLARE @Time_Diff nvarchar(100)

    DECLARE crs CURSOR
    FOR SELECT b.id from table1 a join table2 b on a.ID = b.
    where DATEDIFF(min,DateCreated,SolutionProvided)  < 0

    OPEN crs 

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs 
    INTO @IdToUpdate, @Time_Diff


    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    UPDATE table2 
    SET SolutionProvided=DATEADD(MINUTE, REPLACE(@Time_Diff,'-','+')+10, SolutionProvided)
    WHERE ID = @IdToUpdate

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs 
    INTO @IdToUpdate, @Time_Diff

    END 
    CLOSE crs;
    DEALLOCATE crs;
```